# Saving a prent and child at once in Ember-Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

While playing with ember I was trying to save both a parent and a child at the same time.  What I noticed was that the child's parent_id was always being set to nil.

Then I saw [this issue](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/437) on GitHub.  It seems the functionality was removed from Ember-Data but will be retured later.  Until then we're ment to roll our own adapter to do this.

Reading @tomdale's response it doesn't seem that it would be that hard to implement, but I have a few implementation questions.

How can you tell when a records belongsTo association has changed? And what adapter hook would this go under?

Thanks!

Comment: For the moment, I have to develop other things at the office, bu I will try to have a look at this, as we really need this adapter stuff. I think we have to customize the didSaveRecord https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L34 and as Tom says create a kind dependencies graph in order to wait for dependant records... well easy to say that, but for me, clearly hard to do.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but my solution to this is to save the parent first, observe the record for a response and then use the json response to set the parent on the child, then commit the child. Vice versa would work as well.

Comment: @MehulKar can you post an answer with code that shows your solution?

Answer (score 0):

The store keeps track of relationship changes with special objects. You can ask the store for the change object for a relationship like so:

```js
store.relationshipChangeFor(child.get('clientId'), belongsToAssociationName);
```

If no change was made, it won't return anything.

But it's likely you won't ever need to do that. In the case of a relational data store, the child record will be responsible for persisting its belongsTo associations. On successful create/update, you can blindly mark all of those relationships as resolved and the store won't care if some of them weren't actually dirty.

In fact, that's exactly what `DS.RESTAdapter` does [now](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L34):

```js
DS.RESTAdapter = DS.Adapter.extend({
  // ...

  didSaveRecord: function(store, record, hash) {
    record.eachAssociation(function(name, meta) {
      if (meta.kind === 'belongsTo') {
        store.didUpdateRelationship(record, name);
      }
    });

    store.didSaveRecord(record, hash);
  }

  // ...
});
```

Whenever and wherever you decide you're ready to mark the relationship as resolved, simply call `store.didUpdateRelationship(child, belongsToAssociationName)`.

---

All that being said, the real trick is not in marking the relationships as resolved (since that's already implemented)—it's in delaying the save of the child until after the parent has been created.

We've actually submitted [a pull request](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/440) that does just that. If it'll help you as much as it's helping us, we'd appreciate some support on the request.